# Diagnosing div misalignment

Tags: html, css

Server-side dev here, dabbling in html/css designing.

I have three radio buttons, which I styled as "clickable" boxes. Here's what I mean:

[image]

The above is how the options look on my laptop's Firefox (Ubuntu OS).

Problem is that the same end-result looks visibly misaligned when viewed on mobile chrome/safari/opera etc. See for yourself:

[image]

I've stared at the code for a long time without being able to find the bug. Can an expert help me fix this?

---

Here's my code:

```css
/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.label {
  background: white;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #3cb7dd;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.fx {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.fxjscn {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fxaicn {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mbl {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.mts {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.lsp {
  line-height: 1.55;
}

.clb {
  color: #404040;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="clb mbl mts" style="border:3px solid #ececec;border-radius:12px;overflow:hidden;background:snow;max-width:500px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:97%">

  <div style="margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">

    <input type="radio" name="aud" class="checkbox" id="aud-first" value="1">
    <label class="label" for="aud-first" style="border-top-left-radius:8px;border-top-right-radius:8px;display: inline-flex;align-items: center;">
    <div class="fx fxjscn fxaicn">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlkqOVnCqMpCCYnJf2TB-cm7mfmZGC914FbZZxetEZDJCJqdqqfQ" width="30" height="30" style="padding:0 10px">
        <div class="sp lsp" style="padding:0 10px;text-align:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
    </div>
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="aud" class="checkbox" id="aud-second" value="2">
    <label class="label" for="aud-second" style="display: inline-flex;align-items: center;">
    <div class="fx fxjscn fxaicn">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlkqOVnCqMpCCYnJf2TB-cm7mfmZGC914FbZZxetEZDJCJqdqqfQ" width="30" height="30" style="padding:0 10px">
        <div class="sp lsp" style="padding:0 10px;text-align:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
    </div>
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="aud" class="checkbox" id="aud-third" value="3">
    <label class="label" for="aud-third" style="border-bottom-left-radius:8px;border-bottom-right-radius:8px;display: inline-flex;align-items: center">
    <div class="fx fxjscn fxaicn">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlkqOVnCqMpCCYnJf2TB-cm7mfmZGC914FbZZxetEZDJCJqdqqfQ" width="30" height="30" style="padding:0 10px">
        <div class="sp lsp" style="padding:0 10px;text-align:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
    </div>
    </label>

  </div>

</div>
```

Pardon me for adding the code with some extra stlying frills. They've been included in case they're the culprit in creating the said misalignment (they're part of the original code).

**Note:** Check the misalignment directly in a mobile browser via this link: https://codepen.io/mhb11/pen/BaBpxrr It's *precisely* the same code I've included in the question.

Comment: A `margin-right: 4px;` for the last `label` fixes the alignment, maybe include media-queries to detect view-port sizes and apply styles accordingly.. But still strange though - I will look further into this and fiddle with it a bit

Comment: @ILuvLogix: thanks for the fix, but I would also love to get to the bottom of what's causing this issue.

Comment: I understand you - me too ;) I just removed the middle one as well as the top one and still the same result..

Comment: @iLuvLogix: yea, I can't seem to diagnose the source of the issue either. Nevertheless, I created a codepen link one can directly open in the mobile browser to see the problem in all its glory: https://codepen.io/mhb11/pen/BaBpxrr

Comment: I found the issue- it's your 0x0px checkboxes pushing the last div.. Now I need to find a solution to this..

Comment: @iLuvLogix: ah I see - although why would it just affect mobile browsers? That's super-weird.

Comment: It really is.. But don't worry, I'm sure there's a solution to this (besides adding an explicit margin to the last div..)

Comment: @iLuvLogix: mate what about the answer by Robin Baby below? Seems to fix the problem via utilizing `display:none`. I haven't tested it across browsers yet, but seems to be one way to tackle the issue. Is there another way as well?

Comment: Still looking into it, but if it worked for you in various browser and media-res I guess it's something you could go for..

Comment: Just add an `&nbsp;` after the last label's closing tag. The inputs are causing the issue with how they are positioning themselves relative to the labels. You could probably use the pseudo element `::after` to apply the fix via CSS.

Comment: @Zack: thanks for this. Might as well add this as a possible answer for all future users to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure why, but it has something to do with `inline-flex` and white space related to inline element (or probably a simple bug). Use `flex` instead and you will not have the issue. You will have the same output since you are fixing the width of your elements:

```css
/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.label {
  background: white;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  height: 46px;
  width: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #3cb7dd;
  margin:0 auto -1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.fx {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.fxjscn {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fxaicn {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mbl {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.mts {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.lsp {
  line-height: 1.55;
}

.clb {
  color: #404040;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="clb mbl mts" style="border:3px solid #ececec;border-radius:12px;overflow:hidden;background:snow;max-width:500px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:97%">

  <div style="margin: 0 auto;">

    <input type="radio" name="aud" class="checkbox" id="aud-first" value="1">
    <label class="label" for="aud-first" style="border-top-left-radius:8px;border-top-right-radius:8px;display: flex;align-items: center;">
    <div class="fx fxjscn fxaicn">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlkqOVnCqMpCCYnJf2TB-cm7mfmZGC914FbZZxetEZDJCJqdqqfQ" width="30" height="30" style="padding:0 10px">
        <div class="sp lsp" style="padding:0 10px;text-align:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
    </div>
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="aud" class="checkbox" id="aud-second" value="2">
    <label class="label" for="aud-second" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
    <div class="fx fxjscn fxaicn">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlkqOVnCqMpCCYnJf2TB-cm7mfmZGC914FbZZxetEZDJCJqdqqfQ" width="30" height="30" style="padding:0 10px">
        <div class="sp lsp" style="padding:0 10px;text-align:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
    </div>
    </label>

    <input type="radio" name="aud" class="checkbox" id="aud-third" value="3">
    <label class="label" for="aud-third" style="border-bottom-left-radius:8px;border-bottom-right-radius:8px;display: flex;align-items: center">
    <div class="fx fxjscn fxaicn">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRlkqOVnCqMpCCYnJf2TB-cm7mfmZGC914FbZZxetEZDJCJqdqqfQ" width="30" height="30" style="padding:0 10px">
        <div class="sp lsp" style="padding:0 10px;text-align:left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
    </div>
    </label>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. Wouldn't have thought of this without your help. I'll test it across all browsers relevant for me and get back to you

Answer (score 2):

Right now, the radio buttons are still present in the output. And its affecting the alignment. Instead of setting height and width to 0, and using all those extra properties, just set the display property of input radio button to none. This is the best way to remove elements.

```
.checkbox {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why it was downvoted. Your solution does seem to have solved the problem (when I test it in the codepen I shared). Now I'm going to test it more broadly in my project. Thanks and stay tuned. p.s. could you shed more light on how the radio button was causing the problem (solely in mobile browsers)?

Comment: It isn't solely related to just mobile browsers. I found the issue in my desktop chrome browser as well. Maybe it has got to do something with the computed values. Anyways, please consider accepting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yea I've got your back, but allow me to thoroughly test this first across various browsers and environments.

Comment: @HassanBaig doesn't fix the issue for me and I also confirm that the issue happen in desktop